# Gear selector hard shifting gears

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, shifting, gear-stick

I have a 2006 YZ250F, and whenever I go to shift gears while riding sometimes I really have to kick it hard. Sometimes even twice cause the first one didn't do it. I fiddled with my clutch lever cable a bit but not much of a difference. Sometimes when it's cold if I hold the clutch all the way in, and put it in gear, it immediately stalls. Is my clutch lever still just out of rig or do I have a bigger problem with the actual clutch disk?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I think you've got the problem with the clutch adjustment. Continue to adjust it and see if it makes a difference. Also, make sure you're adjusting it the right way (IE: taking up slack and not giving it more).

Answer (score 1):

Your clutch lever probably isn't adjusted right. The symptoms you described lead me to think your clutch isn't fully engaged when you pull in the lever all the way. Try to adjust it so the clutch engages earlier in the pull (So farther away from the handlebar).